# Python, what is this for loop doing?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, flask

I have scoured the internet and I cannot find any reference to this type of `for` loop:

```
variable = [(item["attribute1"], item["attribute2]") for item in piece_of_json_data]
```

I am using this to update wtform's SelecField choices:

```
form.SelectField.choices = variable
```

but I can only get it to work if I replace one of the attributes in parenthesis with a static number:

```
variable = [(1, item["attribute2"]) for item in piece_of_json_data]
```

but that sets the value of the option field to `"1"`, when I need the option values to be one of the attributes as a string.

Does this create a dict? a tuple? is there some kind of terminology for this that I can use to find documentation?

Comment: This line `variable = [1, item["attribute2]) for item in piece_of_json_data]` has a syntax error, it won't run And the first line creates a list of tuples.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Search the internet again for "list comprehensions python"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: as @rdas said, look up "list comprehensions python"

Comment: Ok so I am using list comprehension to create tuple. All of the examples use numbers, I can't use a string for the first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I now understand that I am using list comprehension to create a tuple. The tuple works fine with both string and integer values. My issue has to do with .choices not accepting a string.

I found that my only problem is that I had coerce set to int on my selectfield, so naturally it wanted an integer.